# RestTemplate response type issue for comsuming web service

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have written following REST web service.

Now i want to consume this web service using RestTemplate.But I am not sure what should be return type for restTemplate.exchange(?).can you please help what should be return type?

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/customercontact/transid/{brokerid}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ResponseEntity<HashMap<String, String>> getTransactionIdWithPublicKey(@PathVariable("brokerid") String brokerid){
         HashMap<String, String> transactionid = customerService.getTransactionid(brokerid);
            if(transactionid != null)
                return new ResponseEntity<HashMap<String, String>>(transactionid,HttpStatus.OK);
            else 
                return new ResponseEntity<HashMap<String, String>>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);

        }
public void doGet( HttpServletRequest request,
                          HttpServletResponse response ) throws IOException
       {

 RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
          HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
          requestHeaders.add("SM_USER", "wbrokere");
          MultiValueMap<String, String> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();   
          HttpEntity<?> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<Object>(body, requestHeaders);
          ResponseEntity<String> responseobj = restTemplate.exchange("http://127.0.0.1:24000/webbroker/getusername", HttpMethod.GET, httpEntity,?);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

the same type used in your Rest Service `HashMap.class`

```
ResponseEntity<HashMap> responseobj = `restTemplate.exchange("http://127.0.0.1:24000/webbroker/getusername", HttpMethod.GET, httpEntity,HashMap.class);`
responseobj.getBody(); //To get the body of the response entity
```

Add Jakson dependencies in The POM.xml

```
<!-- Jackson for Rest Controller -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.8</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: you can use System.out.println("API : " + responseobj.getBody()); to see the result

Comment: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [java.util.HashMap<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>] and content type [application/json;charset=UTF-8]
getting this error

Comment: Add jakson dependencies in your POM, as shown in the updated answer